# Cannot read some files names from asset folder

Tags: android, android-assets

I can read the file names from Asset folder but it is skipping the few file names

It looks like it is only able list me the names which are in English rest of the names i.e non english are skipped . I have attached a image. In image you can see the code , asset folder and Log of the list that i get .

Thanks for your help .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, non-english characters are not allowed in filenames inside APK

Answer (score -1):

renaming folder using small letter without character..
I think it's work..